# Vite App pics appear on Localhost but not on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, image, deployment, localhost, netlify

https://loquacious-taffy-894e70.netlify.app/

This is the link to my app. On my local3000 it opens no problem and the pics are present but here the pics are not displaying.

its a vite app. any idea why? originally the pics were in the src folder but when that didnt work i moved them to public. you may notice only one pic has a src of ./public… i tried both but to no avail.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


import Favorites from "./Favorites";
import { Menu } from "./Menu";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState(() => {
    const localValue = localStorage.getItem("ITEMS");
    if (localValue == null) return [];
    return JSON.parse(localValue);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("ITEMS", JSON.stringify(favorite));
  }, [favorite]);

  const [array, setArray] = useState([
    {
      text: "Check 123",
      name: "Lahmacun",
      image: "../public/lahmacun.jpeg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 456",
      name: "Chicken",
      image: "src/chicken.webp",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 789",
      name: "Veggies",
      image: "src/vegan.jpeg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 012",
      name: "Pho",
      image: "src/pho.jpeg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 012",
      name: "Tacos",
      image: "src/tacos.jpg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 012",
      name: "Babaganoush",
      image: "src/ganoush.jpg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 012",
      name: "Szechuan Chicken",
      image: "src/szechuan.jpg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 012",
      name: "Stinky Tofu",
      image: "src/tofu.jpg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 012",
      name: "BBQ Pork",
      image: "src/bbq.jpg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 012",
      name: "Jerk Chicken",
      image: "src/jerk.jpg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 012",
      name: "Flaky Biscuits",
      image: "src/biscuit.jpg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 012",
      name: "Apple Strudel",
      image: "src/strudel.jpg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 012",
      name: "Ceviche",
      image: "src/ceviche.jpg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
  ]);

  const handleLike = (card) => {
    if (favorite.includes(card)) {
      return;
    } else setFavorite((prev) => [...prev, card]);
  };

  const handleUnlike = (id) => {
    setFavorite(favorite.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div id="app">
      <h1>Recipes To Try</h1>
      <form className="m-2" action="">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-3 ">
            <label className="form-label pt-2" id="searchBar">
              Find A Recipe
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-7 col-5">
            <input
              //onChange={filterRecipes}
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="searchBar"
              placeholder="Search"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-1 col-2">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" id="searchBtn">
              Search
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <Favorites favorite={favorite} handleUnlike={handleUnlike} />
      <Menu array={array} handleLike={handleLike} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
export function Cards({ array, handleLike }) {
  return (
    <>
      {array.map((i) => (
        <div className="col col-md mb-3 mb-sm-0" key={i.id}>
          <div className="card border-secondary border-2 ">
            <img
              src={i.image}
              alt=""
              className="card-img-top"
              style={{ objectFit: "cover" }}
            />
            <div className="card-body" style={{ backgroundColor: "lightgrey" }}>
              <h5 className="card-title">{i.name}</h5>
              <p className="card-text">{i.text}</p>
              <a onClick={() => handleLike(i)} className="btn btn-primary">
                Add to Favorites
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the location of the images,
if the images are in public folder, provide the path of the images as follow

```
{
  text: "Check 123",
  name: "Lahmacun",
  image: "/lahmacun.jpeg",           //This is the way to access the public folder
  id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
  liked: false,
}
```

and if the images are in src folder you have to import the images at the top depending upon the location of image with respect to the file you are importing it in

```
    import chicken from "./chicken.webp" //The path depends on the location of img w.r.t the file 
     {
      text: "Check 456",
      name: "Chicken",
      image: chicken,             //Use the imported image
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
```